# How do I teach Siri to spell names of geographic locations accurately

Tags: iphone, siri

How do I teach Siri to spell names of geographic locations accurately? For example Siri spells Coeur d’Alene as Cortolane or Quarterline and  n e v e r  can find it.  It gets as close as Idaho.

Comment: @patrix I don't think this is a duplicate.  This question is about how to teach Siri to spell location names and not people/contact names.  People can have entries in Contacts and that's how you teach Siri.  Locations/Towns don't have a specific Contact so the steps in that answer don't work for a location. I have this same problem in that Siri doesn't understand my town name even though I have dozens of Contacts that live there.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184537/how-can-i-teach-siri-how-to-spell-my-childs-name-correctly-in-texts