# Apple fitness spells my first name incorrectly

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

My first name is **Martin** but all the messages and awards on the Fitness app (iPhone 12 mini, iOS 16.0) insist on calling me '*Martyn*'. It's not exactly critical but it's annoying.

I've checked my contact details and the 'personal information' on my Apple ID and they are all correct...
Is this a Siri thing, and if so is there an incantation that can persuade it to spell my name right?

Comment: Wild swing [& I see you've already found a workaround] - I know a million Davids, so I throw them all a nickname to more rapidly identify. I wonder if giving yourself a nickname the same as your name would prevent this 'over-familiarity'.

Comment: [Any day now, this will fix itself on its own.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq3iN.jpg)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK it was indeed a *Siri* thing.
Bizarrely when I asked 'who am I' it replied (with the on-screen text) "*you're Martin [surname] but because we're friends I get to call you Martyn*".

The solution was:

1. "hey Siri, stop calling me Martin"
2. "hey Siri, you can call me M-a-r-t-i-n" (i.e.saying each letter)

Job done.

Comment: If you can [teach Siri to spell friends names when you dictate them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/184537), you’re gonna be a legend.

Comment: Could you have fixed this by telling Siri that you are not friends? Tell her that my friends don't call me Martyn.

Comment: @stackoverblown based on the quoted response I suspect that'd result in Siri using "Martin [surname]".